# Adding variables without appending in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

In python, I want to get the sum of x/2 for all x in range(5) without using append to list and sum. How can I do it?

Comment: `s = 0; for x in range(5): s += x / 2`

Comment: Thank you. But it is giving a list of values. what should I do if I just want the last value i.e. the sum (in this case 5)

Comment: @user3447753 5 is not the sum. 4 is. And this is not "giving a list of values". `s` will contain the sum. **Think. Use your common sense. Learn the language. Don't waste our time.**

Comment: @user3447428: The correct result is 5.  Your code gives 4 because it is wrong.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Whatever, then it's 5. I'm accustomed to python 3, where `/` doesn't perform truncation. I was accidentally typing into a Python 2 shell. However, this is irrelevant.

Comment: @user3447753: Your requirements and use case are not clear, and it's unclear where you got stuck.  You can use the [formula for the sum of an arithmetic progression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression#Sum) to get the result in constant time, without looping.

Comment: The code does what is desired. The sum is 5. However could you please tell me how to get just 5 and not 0,.5,1.5... I hv just started to learn the language and working under time crunch.

Comment: @user3447428:  Well, people on SO wil generally tell you when you post wrong code.  The OP was specifically asking abotu Python 2.  Of course nobody can force you to care. :)

Comment: @Ofiris Because `range(5)` is `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`. `0+1/2+2/2+3/2+4/2 = 1/2+1+3/2+2 = 5`.

Comment: @user3447753: What do you mean "get just 5 and not 0, .5..." Perhaps you can show what code you are using that `does what is desired`?

Answer (score 0):

```
# if you're on Python 2 you need the next line:
from __future__ import division

count = 0
for x in range(5):
    count += x / 2
print count
```

`count` will now contain the value `5.0`, which I believe is what you're after.

Comment: You can divide by `2.0` to avoid having to import floor division.

Comment: Yes, you can. But I prefer Python 3's way of working, so I tend to always use it. Also, dividing by 2.0 will always give you a float, but with 3's way, you still end up with an integer if both are ints.

Comment: "but with 3's way, you still end up with an integer if both are ints": no, int/int gives a float in Python 3 even if it divides evenly.  `2/1` gives `2.0`, not `2`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an arbitrary list, you can just manually loop over the items and add the values up:

```
someList = range(5)
total = 0
for x in someList:
    total += x / 2.0
print(total)
```

As you are dividing every item by 2, you can also sum the original item values first and divide once at the end:

```
someList = range(5)
total = 0
for x in someList:
    total += x
total = total / 2.0
print(total)
```

And of course, if you know that you want to sum all numbers from 1 to N (in your case 4), you can also use [simple maths to solve this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF):

```
n = 4
total = (n * (n + 1)) / 2.0 # sum of numbers 1 to N
total = total / 2.0 # result divided by two as per your requirements

# or in one line
total = (n * (n + 1)) / 4.0
```